# nginx get files from inner directory

Tags: nginx

I have a small proble. I set a server block with `root /var/www/my`. I set the location:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

What I want is when I visit my domain to get the files from `/var/www/my/folder`.

I tried with alias but it doesn't work. Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Post the URL that you tried and also the the nginx error logs. Also did you check if you can access something from `/var/www/my` or not?

Comment: I tried domain.com and it works. It shows the index from /var/www/my.

Comment: And as error I get directory index of /var/www/my/folder is forbidden. After I put the alias.

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R nginx /var/www/my` and restart nginx and try